# cat to stderr while reading to end of file marker

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, here-document

Leaving aside the question of whether usage output *should* go to stderr or not, if you had to redirect the output of the cat command below to stderr, how would you do it?

```
function usage {
  cat << "  EOF_USAGE"
  usage: FrameworkBuildScript --clean-all --clean-sdk-only --build-in-externals --debug-only --release-only --resources-only

  --clean-all                   Clean all libraries before building
  --clean-sdk-only              Clean SDK library before building
  --build-in-externals          Include all libraries in the SDK library
  --debug-only                  Build only the debug SDK framework
  --release-only                Build only the release SDK framework
  --resources-only              Build only the SDK resource bundles

  Example: $0 --clean --build-in-externals
  EOF_USAGE
}
```

Comment: Also, meta-question: Would this question be better for super-user? There are so many stack sites now I get a little confused. I'll close it out and move it there if there is consensus.

Comment: This is the right site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
cat << EOF >&2
...
EOF
```

Or:

```
cat >&2 << EOF
...
EOF
```

or:

```
>&2 cat << EOF
...
EOF
```

Or:

```
usage() {
  cat << EOF
...
EOF
} >&2
```

`function usage {` is the `ksh` syntax. It only  makes sense in the AT&T implementations of `ksh` where functions defined that way behave differently. In other shells, that non-standard syntax, where supported behaves the same as the Bourne/POSIX `usage() {` syntax.

Comment: Ha! I had tried that but my test itself was suppressing the stderr. `How not to test this -> ./FrameworkBuildScript.sh >& /dev/null` Thanks for the reality check.

Comment: Actually `function` there is at least one difference between `function usage …` and `usage () …` in bash (and ATT ksh, and zsh, but not mksh), where the `function` behavior is preferable: if `usage` is an alias and alias expansion is on, `usage () …` expands the alias whereas `function usage …` defines a function called `usage`.